# Did I break my PAM configuration files? My user password is no longer accepted

Tags: debian, pam

I followed a guide online and installed some PAM modules:

```
sudo apt-get install libpam-modules libpam-pwquality libpam-cracklib
```

My standard user account "jon" has sudo privileges but now if I try to elevate myself it keeps telling me I'm putting in the password wrong. I even typed it very slowly to make sure. Did I break something?

My `/etc/pam.d/common-*` files look like this.

`/etc/pam.d/common-auth`:

```
auth        required      pam_tally2.so deny=3 unlock_time=300 even_deny_root
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        required      pam_deny.so
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-account`:

```
account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-password`:

```
password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so local_users_only retry=3 minlen=15 gecoscheck maxrepeat=3
password    required      pam_pwhistory.so remember=400 use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so
```

`/etc/pam.d/common-session`:

```
session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

Comment: Boot into rescue mode and put your PAM files back how they were. If you can then elevate, then yes, you broke something in them.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I was able to restore everything and now I'm able to elevate again. Is there any way I can test each line to see what went wrong? I tried with `pamtester` but the syntax isn't clear to me

Comment: Do a binary search: make half of your changes at a time until you narrow it down to a single line that's breaking it.